# REST: Calling a javascript function to send an action to API

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, api, rest

I'm confused with these two:

1. Calling a javascript function to send an action to API.

   `<script type='text/javascript'>`

   > sendAction(
   >          'view',
   >          '24EH1723322222A3',
   >          '42',
   >          'F3D4E3BE31EE3FA069F5434DB7EC2E34',
   >          '/explorer.form?trackid=1369718',
   >          'Fatboy%20Slim%20-%20The%20Rockafeller%20Skank',
   >          '/covers/1369718.jpg',
   >          null);

   `</script>`
2. The example call below (Calling another javascript function to send an action to API).

   `<script type='text/javascript'>`

   > getRecommendations(
   >                'otherusersalsoviewed',
   >                '24EH1723322222A3',
   >                '42');

   `</script>`

Does this mean we need to have two different calls ?

Thanks, regards.
John Maxim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sendAction` function is to send recommendations and the `getRecommendation` function is to retrieve the recommendations.

So, two different actions, two functions.

Comment: Hi James, can I confirm what you mean is that, "both send data and retrieve data" to and from http:// ACME-API/(method) requires each a function which in this example are: javascripts SendAction function and getRecommendation function? thanks.

Comment: Yes, in order to make it simpler, they have wrapped up the calls to send and receive into two functions, so you just call the one that you need.